# Using find with the -size test

Tags: find

I originally asked this question in the Ubuntu Forums, and I thought I understood it, but then I saw somebody use the same command in a different way, and now I'm not sure if I understand it anymore, so I'm humbly asking for your help again.

This is what my standard Pictures directory looks like:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mason mason 1.3M Aug 12 21:35 Beijing-trip.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason  26K May 27  2013 Eiffel-tour.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 1.5M Sep 20  2013 work-buddies.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 155K Apr  2  2013 Q1-profits.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 245K Nov 27  2016 Ireland.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 675K Jun 14  2014 Christmas.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 210K Nov 27  2016 Thanksgiving.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 348K May 27  2013 family.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 805K Feb 27  2015 museum-of-fine-arts.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 8.6K May 26  2013 4th-of-July.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason  20K Mar  9  2013 Taipei.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 1.9M Jun 14  2014 Australia.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 404K Aug 10 21:53 business-trip.jpg
drwxrwxr-x 2 mason mason 4.0K Mar 18 16:55 Wallpapers
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 145K Jan 15  2015 family-reunion.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 mason mason 6.7K Apr  2  2013 friends-and-family.jpg
```

According to the man page for the find command, when using the `-size` test, file sizes get rounded up before getting processed by the `find` command, but what I'd like to know is by how much?

Specifically, how come `find . -size -1M` returns nothing, whereas
`find . -size -8k` prints file `friends-and-family.jpg` as well as directory Wallpapers? Maybe I've always misunderstood this, but in the Ubuntu Forums I first learned that the reason file `friends-and-family.jpg` doesn't show up in the output after typing `find . -size -1M` was because the file gets rounded up to 1MB, and since we specifically asked for files that are less than 1MB, the find command doesn't print the name of the file. But if file `friends-and-family.jpg` gets rounded up to 1MB in the first iteration of the command, how come file `friends-and-family.jpg` ends up in the output when typing `find . -size -8k`? Shouldn't the file `friends-and-family.jpg` get rounded up again to 1MB? If so, then how come a file with a 1MB size shows up in the output when we specifically asked for files less than 8KB?

In addition to the above questions, I also need to know up to what value do the files above get rounded up to when typing the following commands:

```
find . -size -2M
find . -size -3M
find . -size -8k
find . -size -10k
find . -size -2G
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no "first iteration" - the file size is only rounded internally by the `find` command, not actually changed on disk

Comment: Oh, I know that. I know the files aren't modified. The reason I wanted to know up to what value the files get rounded up to internally, is because I want to know why certain files appear in the output and why others don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/find.1.html) (emphasis mine):

> Bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next **unit**.
>   Therefore `-size -1M` is not equivalent to `-size -1048576c`. The
>   former only matches empty files, the latter matches files from 1 to
>   1,048,575 bytes.

Note: next **unit**. With `-1M`, a file of size 6.7k (~0.007M) gets rounded up to 1M, because the unit in consideration is MB. Similarly, with `-8k`, the size gets rounded up to 7k, since the current unit is KB, and that is well within the limits.

So, for these commands:

```
find . -size -2M
find . -size -3M
find . -size -8k
find . -size -10k
find . -size -2G
```

A size of 6.7k will get rounded up to 1M, 1M, 7k, 7k, 1G respectively.

Now, going back to the quoted paragraph, do you see why `-size -1x` for any unit `x` will always only match empty files?

Comment: Ohhh, OK, I see. As soon as a file contains 1 byte of data, it would get rounded up to 1GB when typing find . -size -1G. And since a file that appears as a 1GB file can't be less than 1GB, find doesn't return anything, only empty files. Thanks muru.

Comment: Oh, one more question. If I type find . -size -10k and have two files, one with a size of 26KB and another with a size of 1.3MB, what do those files get rounded up to? My guess is that the 26KB file stays the same, whereas the 1.3MB file gets rounded up to 2.0MB, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @John_Patrick_Mason ~1300KB

Comment: Oh, so you're saying that if the file sizes falls outside of the bound, the find command doesn't even bother to round them up?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the unit here is KB, so the rounding is in KB (1.3MB ~ 1.3*1024 KB, but that size is not precise enough for me to do any meaningful rounding).

Comment: @muru 1.3MB which is 1.3*1024 = 1331.2 Kb should be rounded to 1332Kb when we have `-size -10kb` is not it and not 1300 Kb ?

Comment: @Number you don't have enough significant digits in 1.3 MB to say that.

Comment: @muru Are u saying that 1.3Mb itself is an approximation by `ls` command. If that be so, how did u derived that it will be rounded off to 1300kb in your above comments ?

Comment: @Number945 I'm saying that the number "1.3MB" doesn't hold enough meaningful information in it for representing it precisely in KB.